# How to disable webkit.net image loading in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, webkit, webkit.net

Im trying using webkit.net browser in my wpf project. but loading the images of the page makes it much slower. i dont need em. 
can you please tell me how to disable the images? 
ps: i add the browser programmatically.

Comment: Can you remove the <img> tags using something like HTML agility pack before setting the content of the browser control?

Comment: I tried with agilitypack but the problem is i trie to scrape info from pages after its finnished with javascript (the result basicly ) and with agility pack i couldn't make it work . i got erroren (you need to enable javascript on your browser or something likethat)